# Convert Raw SQL Query to Laravel Eloquent ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX

Tags: laravel, eloquent

can anyone help me turn the query in to Eloquent?

```
 ALTER TABLE `invoices` DROP INDEX 
`invoices_erp_id_origin_customer_id_unique`, ADD UNIQUE 
`invoices_erp_id_origin_customer_id_unique`
 (`erp_id`, `origin`, `customer_id`, `podtyp`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, eloquent only manipulates objects, to alter table use DB facade :)

```
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `invoices` DROP INDEX 
   `invoices_erp_id_origin_customer_id_unique`, ADD UNIQUE 
   `invoices_erp_id_origin_customer_id_unique`
   (`erp_id`, `origin`, `customer_id`, `podtyp`)');
```